# Is it possible to find missed loot in d'Arnise Keep after completing the quest?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

I'm playing through the game and I didn't make any saves before I started the quest to clear out the Keep. When I finished, I found that I had missed the Flail Head [Cold] and thus couldn't complete the Flail of Ages. When I went to the location in the keep where the cold head was supposed to be located, it was mysteriously absent.

Is it possible to collect loot that I missed after I've completed the quest to clear out the keep? Or am I hosed?

P.S. My main is a Fighter class, so I was offered the opportunity to take ownership of the keep -- which I accepted. If that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you take over the keep it technically changes into a different zone.

For instance before it is your stronghold it is

> AR1300: De'Arnise Keep Outdoor

Then after you make it your stronghold it is

> AR1304: De'Arnise Keep Outdoor (Stronghold)

This should explain the problem.  In short, yes you are hosed unless you want to replay the area or cheat the item in and pretend it never happened.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, except I also dumped loads of items onto the ground before the map switcheroo, which at first seemed forever lost, as "cheating" items back into your inventory is a process much more tedious than simply picking them back up from where you left them. However it's not to late to just do that!

As Brian said the stronghold map is a different one than the normal one. All you have to do to get full access to the old map is "teleport" yourself to the old map using the console.

Activate the [console](http://gemrb.org/iesdp/appendices/clua/bg2.htm) by following these steps:
"Open the Baldur.ini file (located in the BG2 installaion directory).
Find the line [Program Options] and add the text Debug Mode=1 underneath."

Then while in the game, select the characters you want to teleport.

Then press ctrl and space together. That opens a little window you can type in.

Now type CLUAConsole:MoveToArea("AR1300") and press enter.

All selected characters should now have moved to that area. Finish what you wanted to finish there.

Then open the console (ctrl+space), press the up-arrow key and change AR1300 to AR1304, to teleport yourself back to the stronghold version of things.